# Typo3 - Image Gallery with Typoscript from Ressources with Classnames

Tags: typoscript

Im having a little problem with typo3 (Version 7LTS). I want to create a little image gallery from the ressources images of a page and i am getting these images with this typoscript:

```
lib.produktSliderBig = FILES
lib.produktSliderBig {

  references {
    table = pages
    data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
  }
  sorting = sorting_foreign
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
      stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
        }
        20 = TEXT
  20 {
    data = file:current:description
    wrap = <p class="flex-caption">|</p>
  }
     altText.data = file:current:description
     wrap = <li class="big">|</li>
    }
     stdWrap {
     wrap = <ul class="produkte-big">|</ul>
  }
}

page.77.subparts.produktSliderBig < lib.produktSliderBig
```

This creates this output:

```
<ul class="produkte-big"><li class="big"><img src="image1.jpg" width="1000" height="1000"   alt="" ><p class="flex-caption"></p></li>
<li class="big"><img src="image2.jpg" width="1000" height="1000"   alt="" ><p class="flex-caption"></p></li>
<li class="big"><img src="image3.jpg" width="1000" height="1000"   alt="" ><p class="flex-caption"></p></li></ul>
```

Now i need to add a classname to my img tag - like this:

```
<img class="image1" src...
<img class="image2" src...
```

But i don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

Here's a solution with jquery - but adding classnames with typoscript would be more eleganz:

```
$(".produkte").children().each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('img').addClass('hover-image'  + (i+1));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had some syntax errors, and as far as I know you need a counter ... :

```
lib.produktSliderBig = FILES
lib.produktSliderBig {
    references {
        table = pages
        data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
    }
    sorting = sorting_foreign
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = LOAD_REGISTER
        10 {
            Counter.cObject = TEXT
            Counter.cObject.data = register:Counter
            Counter.cObject.wrap = |+1
            Counter.prioriCalc = intval
        }
        20 = IMAGE
        20 {
            file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
            titleText.data = file:current:title
            altText.data = file:current:alternative
            params.data = register:Counter
            params.dataWrap = class="image|"
            stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
        }
        30 = TEXT
        30 {
            # this is a fallback if description is not available
            data = file:current:description // file:current:name
            stdWrap.wrap = <p class="flex-caption">|</p>
        }
        wrap = <li class="big">|</li>
    }
    stdWrap {
        wrap = <ul class="produkte-big">|</ul>
    }
    RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```